# Extending theme with material-ui@next and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

When creating my theme for `material-ui` I added two new palette options that give me a better range of lights and darks. I have extended the `Theme` type to indicate this

```
import {Theme} from "material-ui/styles";
import {Palette} from "material-ui/styles/createPalette";

export interface ExtendedTheme extends Theme {
    palette: ExtendedPalette
}

export interface ExtendedPalette extends Palette {
    light: Color,
    dark: Color,
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to use these additional options in the `WithStyles` render helper

```
const styles = (theme : ExtendedTheme) => ({ root: {color: theme.light['100'] }});

export interface MyProps {classes: {[index: string] : string}};
const MyComponent = (props : MyProps) => {...};

// Type ExtendedTheme is not assignable to Theme
export default withStyles(styles : StyleRulesCallback)(MyComponent);
```

Functionally my code works fine in pure javascript, but since the types are different it throws the error. The typings for material-ui expect a type of `Theme` to be the sole argument the the style callback function:

```
export type StyleRulesCallback<ClassKey extends string = string> = (theme: Theme) => StyleRules<ClassKey>;
```

I thought that extending an interface would work in a polymorphic way so that `ExtendedTheme` would implement `Theme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer I've come up with is to make my custom options optional like so

```
export interface ExtendedPalette extends Palette {
    light?: Color,
    dark?: Color,
}
```

Then in my styles callback I have to check that those options exist, which is kind of a hassle, but I don't think there is any other workaround

```
const styles = (theme : ExtendedTheme) => { 
    let light = theme.palette.light[100];
    if(light === undefined) light = theme.common.white;
    { root: {color: light }}
};
```

The reason for this is that the Theme object is passed to the callback when I use `withStyles` but the typings for this callback use the `Theme` type because they have no way of knowing about my `ExtendedTheme` type. The conflict comes in when `ExtendedTheme` must have options that `Theme` knows nothing about. By making those extra options optional `Theme` can still comply with `ExtendedTheme`.  Basically an extended interface can be passed where its parent is expected, but its parent cannot be passed where the extended interface is expected, unless the extended interface is extended in a way that the Parent can still comply.

A simpler example is instructive.

```
export interface Foo {foo: string};
export interface Bar extends Foo {bar: string}

function getFoo(f : Foo) {console.log(f.foo)}
function getBar(b : Bar) {console.log(b.bar)} 
function getFooBar(fb: Bar) {console.log(fb.foo, fb.bar)}

const f : Foo = {foo: 'foo'}
const b : Bar = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}

getFoo(f) // foo
getFoo(b) // foo
getBar(f) // Error Incompatible Type
getBar(b) // bar
getFooBar(f) // Error Incompatible Type
getFooBar(b) // foo bar
```

`getFoo(b)` works because `Bar` is guaranteed to have at least everything that `Foo` has. `getBar(f)` and `getFooBar(f)` both fail because the compiler sees that the type `Foo` does not have the key `bar`

By redefining `Bar` like so

```
export interface Bar extends Foo {bar? : string}
```

The compiler now knows that Foo matches the minimum qualifications for the `Bar` type, but you have to check for an implicit null. So this will work

```
getBar(f)
```

But the compiler will yell about implicit nulls, which is good, because `f.bar` is undefined. So you have to redefine your function like so

```
function getBar(b : Bar) {
    let bar = b.bar
    if(bar === undefined) bar = b.foo;
    console.log(bar);
}

getBar(b) // bar
getBar(f) // foo
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module '@material-ui/core' {
  interface Theme {
    colors: {
      success: {
        dark: string,
        light: string,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, you may declare the module in your App component as well as wrapping the children in a `ThemeProvider`:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, colors, ThemeOptions } from '@material-ui/core';

declare module '@material-ui/core' {
  interface Theme {
    colors: {
      success: {
        dark: string,
        light: string,
      }
    }
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    colors: {
      success: {
        dark: colors.green[600],
        light: colors.green[300],
      },
    } as ThemeOptions,
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <a href="https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/">Theming</a>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
```

Comment: Note that where you declare the module you should import the interface you're extending. I.e. `import { Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";`