# How to extend Material-UI Theme with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Typescript is always complaining about certain properties missing in the palette. My app works just fine if I add `//@ts-ignore`, but I obviously want to avoid that. I'm new to Typescript and here is what I've tried.

```
import createMuiTheme, { ThemeOptions, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import { PaletteOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';

interface IPaletteOptions extends PaletteOptions {
    chip: {
      color: string,
      expandIcon: {
        background: string,
        color: string,
      },
    },
}
interface ITheme extends Theme {
  palette: IPaletteOptions,
}

const theme: ITheme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontWeightMedium: 600,
    fontFamily: ['Open Sans', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#43C099',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#7AF3CA',
    },
    chip: {
      color: '#C2C3C6',
      expandIcon: {
        background: '#808183',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
    },
  },
} as ThemeOptions);
```

This throws an error,

```
Type 'Theme' is not assignable to type 'ITheme'.
  Types of property 'palette' are incompatible.
    Property 'chip' is missing in type 'Palette' but required in type 'IPaletteOptions
```

This is a confusing error for me, because type I'm not using the type `Palette` anywhere.

How can I properly extend the palette here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending theme with material-ui@next and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014816/extending-theme-with-material-uinext-and-typescript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Solution

```
import createMuiTheme, { Theme, ThemeOptions } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";
import { Palette } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";

interface IPalette extends Palette {
  xxx: {}
}
interface ITheme extends Theme {
  palette: IPalette;
}
interface IThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
  palette: IPalette;
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    ...
    xxx: {}                                        // Type been checked
  }
} as IThemeOptions)                                // Use customized ThemeOptions type

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: ITheme) => ({ // Use customized Theme type
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.xxx                       // Work with no type error
  }
}));
```

---

#### Refer

If we look at the [createMuiTheme.d.ts](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.d.ts)

```
import { Palette, PaletteOptions } from './createPalette';

export interface ThemeOptions {
  palette?: PaletteOptions;
  ...
}

export interface Theme {
  palette: Palette;
  ...
}

export default function createMuiTheme(options?: ThemeOptions, ...args: object[]): Theme;
```

We would find that `Theme` and `ThemeOptions` play a different role.

- Theme: return type
- ThemeOptions: params type

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm having trouble understanding, I want to extend the palette (ie, I want it to have the original palette props + my own custom ones). So, why do `interface ITheme extends Theme { palette: Palette }`? Or should I make my own `IPalette` and do `interface ITheme extends Theme { palette: Palette<IPalette> }`? Because the issue is that Typescript tells me `chip` doesn't exist on `type Palette`, so should I make my own `interface IPalette { chip: { ... } }`?

Comment: @MikeK Updated.

Answer (score 25):

This can be solved much easier via [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

MUI v5

`material-ui.d.ts`

```
import "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    chip: {
      color: string;
      expandIcon: {
        background: string;
        color: string;
      };
    };
  }
}
```

MUI v4

`material-ui.d.ts`

```
import { PaletteOptions } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    chip: {
      color: string;
      expandIcon: {
        background: string;
        color: string;
      };
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The revealed explanation is also could be found here
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/extend-material-ui-theme-in-typescript-a462e207131f

Comment: In my case I had to use module augmentation, mapped types, and const assertions to make my custom theme object work with TypeScript, and also provide helpful intellisense: https://dragoshmocrii.com/material-ui-custom-theme-and-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

In React typescript, you have to declare that the variable is a type of ThemeOptions when using the theme in the child component.

```
import { ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material';

const ChildComponent: React.FC<Props> = (Props) => {
const theme:ThemeOptions  = useTheme();
  const theme:ThemeOptions = React.useContext(ThemeContext); 
return ()}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'm extending in MUI v5

```
import { PaletteColorOptions } from '@mui/material';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {

  // add inside palette
  interface PaletteOptions {
    customStatus: PaletteColorOptions;
    colorDark: PaletteColorOptions;
    customDanger: PaletteColorOptions;
  }

  // customize inside palette.background
  interface TypeBackground {
    light: string;
  }

  // add inside theme
  // interface ThemeOptions {
  // }

}

// extend typography inside the theme
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTypography' {
  interface FontStyle {
    font1: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for MUI v5

```
// material-ui.d.ts
import {
  PaletteOptions,
  PaletteColorOptions,
  Palette,
  SimplePaletteColorOptions,
  ColorPartial,
} from '@mui/material/styles/createPalette'

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    customRgba?: PaletteColorOptions
  }
  export interface Palette {
    customRgba: SimplePaletteColorOptions & ColorPartial
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { createTheme, PaletteOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

interface CustomTheme extends PaletteOptions {
  dark: {
    main: string;
  };
}

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#393E46",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#00ADB5",
    },
    dark: {
      main: "#222831",
    },
    light: {
      main: "#EEEEEE",
    },
  },
} as {
  palette: CustomTheme;
});

export default theme;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).