# Recreating this theme.js to theme.tsx

Tags: typescript, material-ui

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/zreecespieces/material-ui-course-create-react-app)

I'm trying to recreate this material-ui theme.js to typescript and implement into the components using

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  estimateButton: {
    ...theme.typography.estimate,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.orange,
    borderRadius: 50,
    height: 45,
    width: 145,
    marginRight: 40,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light
    }
```

I have tried using module augmentation that was on the material UI docs. I also browsed through similar questions here in StackOverflow but I still can't get it to work. It feels like making this work in jsx is simpler compared to typescript but I would still like to learn how it works.

[Theme.js](https://github.com/zreecespieces/material-ui-course-create-react-app/blob/master/src/components/ui/Theme.js)

I tried using this solution from one of the answers here but doesn't seem to work

```
import createMuiTheme, {
  Theme,
  ThemeOptions,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createTypography";

interface ITypography extends Typography {
  tab: {
    fontFamily: String;
    textTransform: String;
    fontWeight: Number;
    color: String;
    fontSize: String;
  };
}
interface ITheme extends Theme {
  typography: ITypography;
}
interface IThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
  typography: ITypography;
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontWeightMedium: 600,
    fontFamily: ["Open Sans", "Arial", "sans-serif"].join(","),
    tab: {
      fontFamily: "Raleway",
      textTransform: "none",
      fontWeight: 700,
      color: "white",
      fontSize: "1rem",
    },
  },
} as IThemeOptions); // Use customized ThemeOptions type

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: ITheme) => ({
  // Use customized Theme type
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.tab, // Work with no type error
  },
}));
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want... You have to give your theme to the ThemeProvider, than it will be available in makeStyles (weather or not you use typescript). Here is the doc https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

Comment: This whole project uses jsx. I'm trying to recreate it in typescript however typescript doesn't allow me to add custom properties such as tab :{} . Kindly check what the docs said here https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme @JeromeBu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend Material-UI Theme with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120760/how-to-extend-material-ui-theme-with-typescript)